# XCode Objective-C Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, twitterkit

recently started to make apps with XCode. I got this error after I installed cocoapods and used pod init and install... haven't even started to write codes and it failed... Any idea what might cause it? I tried all the methods online but didn't work

The following pictures are the screenshots of errors:

[image]

[image]

[new screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhJZU.png)

Comment: You need to add additional frameworks to your project.

Comment: 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TWTRWebAuthenticationViewController.o)
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TWTRLoginUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Comment: @ChanWarde I pod install and update TwitterKit. Do I need to add more?

Comment: It takes me forever just to import a library/package... why is it so difficult x_x and tons of tons of errors...

Comment: Ok, @J.Titor.0 send me a copy of your project will resolve all issues and send it back to you. Plus write the solution to every error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `SafariServices` framework is only available on iOS9 and above. and Please ensure that you have added `SafariServices` Framework and to  run on older versions of iOS ? Try setting it as `optional` otherwise `required`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried adding safariservices.framework but still have the same error. I noticed that my pods framework is showing as red color. Could it be something wrong in my pod framwork?

Comment: Can you pls attach that screen shot?

Comment: What's your deployment Target?

Comment: Minmum Deployment target ( iOS version) in xcode? And can you clear the derived data &  reinstall the pods.

Comment: 8.0... yeah I tried several times reinstalling the pods... it might be my xcode out of date... trying to upgrade it now

Comment: Set Deployment Target to 9 or 9.3

Comment: I fixed it by updating my xcode ; - ;... thanks for the help!